# Matlab - OOP Methods

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object, simulation

I am working on some OOP in MATLAB. I am currently creating a class as follows:

```
classdef uavclass
    properties
        %all properties of the uav
        position = [0,0,0]
        charge = 100;
        destination = [0,0,0];
        maxVertClimb = 2;
        maxHorizSpeed = 5;
        sensorRange = 25;
        unloadingTime = 60;
        safeDistance = 5;
        chargingTime = 300;
        minCruiseAlt = 20;
        maxCruiseAlt = 70;
    end
    methods(Static)
        function uav = uavclass(x,y,z)
            uav.position = [x,y,z]
        end
    end
end
```

I can create a `uav` at a `position` by calling:

```
uav1 = uavclass(20,20,0);
uav2 = uavclass(40,40,0);
uav3 = uavclass(50,50,0);
uav4 = uavclass(80,80,0);
uav5 = uavclass(90,90,0);
```

Whenever I try to use any kind of method on the `uav` objects I get an error. An example is simply trying change the `sensorRange` of some `uav`

```
    function changesense(b) 
        uav.sensorRange = b
    end
```

have also tried `uavclass.sensorRange`. I try to call this with `uav1.changesense(5)`, but it does not change the value. I have also tried with and without using `(Static)` for methods, and `changesense(uav1,b)` etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should upvote and accept an answer. It seems you are only asking questions but never giving anything back (by looking at your profile page). So if my answer helped you, please do the appropriate things.

Comment: Your method is of the same name as class name. That means this method is a constructor. I don't think constructors can be inside `Static` section but rather in `methods` section of public access. Constructors must return a reference to an object whose instance is being created; in your case it is `uav`. Assigning any value to any property will change those properties and state of your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to have a first parameter to each method which defines the object which is modified. That means, you need to implement it like this:

```
function obj = changesense(obj, b) 
    obj.sensorRange = b
end
```

This is just the concept how it works in MATLAB. 
Also have a look here for some simple OOP examples:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/getting-familiar-with-classes.html and this docu about different types of methods: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html#brqy87j
In case you wanna use a static method (not working in the object's context, you would NOT need the first argument).

It is the same concept like `self` in Python.

And everything you'd want to know about OOP in matlab is fully documented in any sub-page of this main page: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim, i tried creating a different method,

        function changeCharge(uav,b)
            uav.charge = b
        end

and tried calling it with uav1.changeCharge(50) as well as changeCharge(uav1,50), and also changeCharge(uav,50), and finally uav.changeCharge(uav1,50), but it still will not modify the variable of the object uav1.

Comment: You'd also have to return the object `obj` frmo the method, I edited my answer. See more here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html. In your case, this would yield: `function self = changeCharge(self, b) self.charge = b; end`. I would rather use `self` or `obj` as GENERAL terms for the self-object (always), instead of `uav`, because `uav` could make you confuse later, because you also name your other variables `uav1, uav2 etc...`

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this problem. The "quick-and-dirty"-est one would be annotating the `properties` section with the following:

```
properties (Access = public)
```

this way you will be able to read and write the the object properties (or "*fields*") as if it was a `struct`.

---

Several notes:

1. You can create several `methods` and `properties` blocks, each with their own attributes. For example, this way you can some `methods` blocks to contain `Static` methods, while other can define `private` etc. I would suggest separating your properties into two blocks, where the 1<sup>st</sup> contains some constants, and the other contains your actual "instance variables":

   ```
   properties (Constant = true) %// Class constants
       MAX_VERT_CLIMB = 2;
       MAX_HORIZ_SPEED = 5;
       ...
   end

   properties (Access = public, Constant = false) %// Instance variables
       sensorRange@double scalar = [];
       position@double vector = [];
       ...
   end
   ```
2. Accessor & Mutator methods: as mentioned in [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37223937/3372061) one might want to use methods to change and access the values of instance fields, as these generally provide more flexibility in the long run. You can read more about this in e.g. Bloch's *Effective Java* "**Item 14: In public classes, use accessor methods, not public fields**".
3. I don't think it's correct to annotate the `methods` block which contains the constructor with any [Method Attributes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html). I say this only because this is how it appears in MATLAB's examples, I *believe* this has something to do with subclassing certain "convenience classes" that require the constructor block to have no attributes, but there may very well be another explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple change in your code should do.

```
classdef uavclass
    properties
        %all properties of the uav
        position = [0,0,0]
        charge = 100;
        destination = [0,0,0];
        maxVertClimb = 2;
        maxHorizSpeed = 5;
        sensorRange = 25;
        unloadingTime = 60;
        safeDistance = 5;
        chargingTime = 300;
        minCruiseAlt = 20;
        maxCruiseAlt = 70;
    end
    methods
        function uav = uavclass(x,y,z) % this is constructor
            uav.position = [x,y,z];
        end
    end
end
```

Note that a name of your function is the same as the name of a class. That suggests that this function is a constructor. You should remove the `Static` attribute in `methods`. Constructors must also follow a couple of rules. One of them is that a function must return a reference to an object that a constructor creates, in your case it is `uav` but it could be anything. I usually use `obj`.

Remember that you have decided to make your properties public. Otherwise you could use one of the attributes: `private` or `protected` and control access to properties by setters or getters.

If you define any other method in your class, the first argument must be your a reference to your object. If you make changes to your object, your function needs to return this variable! Matlab makes changes only to a copy of an input object. This object is lost, unless you return it from a function.

```
classdef uavclass
    % code
    methods
        function obj = uavclass(x,y,z)
            obj.position = [x,y,z];
        end
        function uav = mymethod(uav, arg1, arg2) % uav contains a reference to an instance of an object
            uav.minCruiseAlt = arg1;
            uav.maxCruiseAlt = arg2;
        end
    end
end
```